# How to implement admob banner on multiple activities

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, admob, banner

I have an app with 2 activities, I used Kotlin. I managed to implement an admob banner with no issues on the main activity, now I want another banner on the second activity, how do I do that. I have searched everywhere but the solutions I get are for implementing the same banner on two activities, but what I want is for each activity to have its own banner. Please note that I am using kotlin not Java, and I have no java experience.

My activity_main.xml looks like this

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_background"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
```

My MainActivity.kt looks like this

```
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713")
    adView.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
```

When I do the same for the second activity and run the app, the first activity runs and show the ad, now when I move on to the next activity it crashes. how is it done exactly?

Comment: Do you want to integrate google AdMob banner ads for all of your activities? That what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Can't you do the same way you did it for Mainactivity.

Comment: let me try again, it was giving this error:

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.poc.com.eas/com.poc.com.eas.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference.                                                                       Thats the error Im getting after doing the same as Main Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting the following error:

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.poc.com.eas/com.poc.com.eas.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference.
```

Is because you are trying to call the `loadAd()` method on the same view you had in your past activity which is no longer active. So what you need to do is define an AdView for your banners on each of the activies and then when you start your Main2Activity you need to call `adView2.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())`

Comment: Won't it be duplicate call for same ad unit? increases ad requests and decrease displayed impressions?